# How to fix - ImportError: No module named urls?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm getting following error when I use `python manage.py runserver` in my django project :

[image]

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no ``urls`` in [``rest_framework_swagger``](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/tree/master/rest_framework_swagger).

Comment: @Ankit can you tell which version of swagger is this ?

Comment: @ErnestTen Then please tell me the correct way of using it

Comment: @RajaSimon I'm using https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger

Comment: Yeah right but I need the version number! what "pip freeze" gives ?

Comment: `rest_framework_swagger` has no `urls` module. It uses django's inbuilt auth modules. If you use `django-rest-framework`, you can use  `url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))` in your urls.py.

Comment: Thanks to all actually it was because of django swagger version, older version of swagger has urls.py but not in new version

Comment: @Ankit so.. how did you resolve it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As we ca see there no `urls` file in `rest_framework_swagger`
If you use `django-rest-framework`, you can follow the said by @kapil
as follows

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

in your `urls.py` file.

Well recommend using `tasypie` for Django Rest APIs, it's easy to use, you do the same using `tastypie` by adding

```
url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
```

in `urlpatterns` list in `urls.py` file

you can find more about tastypie [Here](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Recommending a different technology (tastypie) is not a good answer to a question about why swagger is failing. It would be better to just figure out why swagger isn't working and then perhaps make the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of Django rest swagger doesn't have the urls module.
One should add Swagger to their project in the following way (Django Rest Swagger version 2.1.1):

```
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Swagger API')
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^docs/', schema_view),
]
```

Please follow [this](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) link for more details.